# Plotly legendgroup for subplots so a single legend controls all charts

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm using `plotly` in `r` to generate a number of subplots. A toy example is shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

## Toy Example
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3("Diamonds"),
  plotlyOutput("plot", height = 600)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # reduce down the dataset to make the example simpler
  dat <- diamonds %>% 
    filter(clarity %in% c("I1", "IF")) %>%
    mutate(clarity = factor(clarity, levels = c("I1", "IF")))

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    # Generates the chart for a single clarity
    byClarity <- function(df){

      Clarity <- df$clarity[1];

      plot_ly(df, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~cut, name = ~clarity) %>%
        add_trace(
          type="bar"
          ## Also tried adding this with no success
          # legendgroup = ~cut
        ) %>%
        layout(
          barmode = "stack"
        )
    }

    dat %>% 
      split(.$clarity) %>% 
      lapply(byClarity) %>%
      subplot(nrows = NROW(.), shareX = TRUE, which_layout = "merge")
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to make the legends such that clicking on a 'Cut' on the legend will show/hide that 'Cut' from *both* charts instead of just the chart associated with that legend.

[image: DefaultVsIdeal]

I looked at legendgroup but can't figure out how to associate it with `cut` instead of `clarity` (`clarity` is the grouping I'm using to make the subplots).

*I also need the solution to work with raw `plot_ly` and not `ggplotly` as there are other `plot_ly` functionalities I need that aren't available in `ggplotly`.*

Any help would be appreciated. I am using `plotly_4.5.2`, `dplyr_0.5.0`, and `shiny_0.14`.

Comment: Did you try `Better practice under plotly 4.0 and above.` in this answer:
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122127/2296728`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a solution using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
dat <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(clarity %in% c("I1", "IF")) %>%
  mutate(clarity = factor(clarity, levels = c("I1", "IF")))
# Function for nice labels
k_label <- function(x) {
 c(0, paste0((x)/1000,"K")[-1])
}
# ggplot
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=carat, y=price, fill=cut)) + 
           geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
           facet_wrap(~clarity,nrow=2, scales = "free_y") +
           scale_y_continuous(labels = k_label) + 
           theme_minimal() + ylab("") + xlab("") +
           theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
# a plotly
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm looking for a solution that works with raw `plot_ly` and not `ggplotly` as there are other `plot_ly` functionalities I need that aren't available in `ggplotly`... I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @adilapapaya I still thinking it is not possible (so far) at least in `R`. Could be helpful to ckeck whether it is possible in `python` or `matlab`. There are some differences between the softwares.

Comment: @adilapapaya I'm encountering this problem too, were you ever able to come up with a solution?

Comment: @Danny unfortunately not. :-/

Comment: @Danny, if you are still looking for a solution, perhaps my answer can help you out

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `legendgroup = ~cut` to both traces and setting `showlegend = F` for one of them. Then in layout set `showlegend = T`

Like this:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~cut, name = ~clarity, legendgroup = ~cut, showlegend = T) %>%
    add_trace( type="bar", legendgroup = ~cut, showlegend = F) %>%
    layout(
      barmode = "stack",showlegend = T
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example with pure plot_ly code. However, it is not my proudest work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
dat <- diamonds %>% 
    filter(clarity %in% c("I1", "IF")) %>%
    mutate(clarity = factor(clarity, levels = c("I1", "IF")))

firstPlot <- plot_ly(data = dat, x = ~carat, y = ~depth, legendgroup = ~cut, color = ~cut)
secondPlot <- plot_ly(data = dat, x = ~carat, y = ~price, legendgroup = ~cut, color = ~cut)

together <- subplot(firstPlot, secondPlot)
together
```

[image: subplot works! But not ideal]
Which yields this, but the legend still has duplicates.. This can be resolved with the `showLegend = FALSE` parameter, but not in the traditional manner..

```
for (layer in 1L:(length(together$x$data) / 2L)) {
    together$x$data[[layer]]$showlegend <- FALSE
}
together
```

[image: Correctly grouped legend that is interactive!]
And this gives the final plots that are still linked together, while only displaying one of the values.
If you plan on using more than two subplots, the for loop (which can be an lapply as well) can be altered to select all layers *except* the first by doing `length(unique(dat$cut)):length(together$x$data)` which is more robust in the long run.

Note: this works on most plot_ly graphs but not in all (e.g. `'box'`), so if you want to apply this but still need help, let me know!