# Group legend in Plotly with Python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm discovering Plotly on Python and I'm trying to plot "grouped" subplots.

Here is an example of code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, start_cell="bottom-left")

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

y1 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
y2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

z1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
z2 = [6,6,2,2,3,3,1,1,0,0]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=z1), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=z2), row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

which gives this result:
[image]

But what I want to do is to "group" the `y` plots and `z` plots in the same legend: so in the figure, the blue line and the red line should appear on the same color and correspond to one entry on the legend (and idem for `trace 2` and `trace 3`).

I found some "hand-crafted" solution setting manually the color of the graph, and displaying the legend once over two, but this is not optimal...

Here is an example of what the figure should look like :

[image: result]
The legend entry "trace 1" would correspond to both `y1` and `y2`, and "trace 2" to `z1`and `z2`. So when I ckick on the legend, both lines are hidden.

I don't know if this is quite clear, but here is another topic with the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065931/plotly-legendgroup-for-subplots-so-a-single-legend-controls-all-charts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify for each graph the legend you want to group. You can also use lines to set the same color for each group.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, start_cell="bottom-left")

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

y1 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
y2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

z1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
z2 = [6,6,2,2,3,3,1,1,0,0]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='markers+lines', line=dict(color='Crimson'), legendgroup='group'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='markers+lines', line=dict(color='Blue'), legendgroup='group2'), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=z1, mode='markers+lines', line=dict(color='Crimson'), legendgroup='group'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=z2, mode='markers+lines', line=dict(color='Blue'), legendgroup='group2'), row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is based on this example from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend-items).  If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: I think I mis-explained what I wanted... I edited the main message to show  what the result should look like

Comment: After re-reading the edited question, I'm not sure what your intentions are. Why does the added line graph on the left side have green and red overlapping?

Comment: oh, this is because I just painted with photofiltre according to the color I wanted, and this is not perfect ! So the two lines corresponding to `y1` and `y2` should be totaly blue, and the lines corresponing to `z1` and `z2` in red (with no green or overlap, sorry about that)

Comment: If you want to change the line color as you wish, you can change the color specification to 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Crimson', 'Crimson'.